# Error when trying to implement MERGE algorithm merging to sorted lists of integers in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, merge

I'm new to both algorithms AND programming.

As an intro to the MERGE algorithms the chapter introduces **first** the MERGE algorithm **by itself**. It merges and sorts an array consisting of 2 **sorted sub-arrays**.

I did the pseudocode on paper according to the book:

[image]

*Source: "Introduction to Algorithms
Third Edition"  Thomas H. Cormen Charles E. Leiserson Ronald L. Rivest Clifford Stein*

Since I am implementing it in `python3` I had to change some lines given that indexing in python starts at **0** unlike in the pseudocode example of the book.

Keep in mind that the input is one array that contains 2 SORTED sub-arrays which are then merged and sorted, and returned. I kept the prints in my code, so you can see my checks...

```
#!/anaconda3/bin/python3

import math
import argparse

# For now only MERGE slides ch 2 -- Im defining p q and r WITHIN the function
# But for MERGE_SORT p,q and r are defined as parameters!

def merge(ar):
    '''
    Takes as input an array. This array consists of 2 subarrays that ARE ALLREADY sorted 
    (small to large). When splitting the array into half, the left
    part will be longer by one if not divisible by 2. These subarrays will be
    called left and right. Each of the subarrays must already be sorted. Merge() then 
    merges these sorted arrays into one big sorted array. The sorted array is returned.
    '''
    print(ar)
    p=0 # for now defining always as 0
    if len(ar)%2==0:
        q=len(ar)//2-1 # because indexing starts from ZERO in py
    else:
        q=len(ar)//2 # left sub array will be 1 item longer 
    r=len(ar)-1 # again -1 because indexing starts from ZERO in py
    print('p', p, 'q', q, 'r', r)

    # lets see if n1 and n2 check out
    n_1 = q-p+1 # lenght of left subarray
    n_2 = r-q # lenght of right subarray
    print('n1 is: ', n_1)
    print('n2 is: ', n_2)
    left = [0]*(n_1+1) # initiating zero list of lenght n1
    right=[0]*(n_2+1)
    print(left, len(left))
    print(right, len(right))

    # filling left and right
    for i in range(n_1):# because last value will always be infinity
        left[i] = ar[p+i]
    for j in range(n_2):
        right[j] = ar[q+j+1]
        #print(ar[q+j+1])
        #print(right[j])
    # inserting infinity at last index for each subarray
    left[n_1]=math.inf
    right[n_2]=math.inf
    print(left)
    print(right)
    # merging: initiating indexes at 0
    i=0
    j=0
    print('p', p)
    print('r', r)
    for k in range(p,r):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            ar[k]=left[i]
            # increase i
            i += 1
        else:
            ar[k]=right[j]
            #increase j
            j += 1
    print(ar)
#############################################################################################################################
# Adding parser
#############################################################################################################################
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MERGE algorithm from ch 2')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--array', type=str, metavar='', required=True, help='One List of integers composed of 2 sorted halves. Sorting must start from smallest to largest for each of the halves.')
args = parser.parse_args()
args_list_st=args.array.split(',') # list of strings
args_list_int=[]
for i in args_list_st:
    args_list_int.append(int(i))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    merge(args_list_int)
```

#### The problem:

When I try to sort the array as shown in the book the merged array that is returned contains two 6es and the 7 is lost.

```
$ ./2.merge.py -a=2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6
[2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6]
p 0 q 3 r 7
n1 is:  4
n2 is:  4
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 5
[2, 4, 5, 7, inf]
[1, 2, 3, 6, inf]
p 0
r 7
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

This does how ever not happen with arrays of any number higher than 6.

```
$ ./2.merge.py -a=2,4,5,7,1,2,3,8
[2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8]
p 0 q 3 r 7
n1 is:  4
n2 is:  4
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 5
[2, 4, 5, 7, inf]
[1, 2, 3, 8, inf]
p 0
r 7
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

I showed it to a colleague in my class without success. And I've walked it through manually with numbers on paper snippets but withouth success. I hope someone can find my silly mistake because I'm completely stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `r` is the index of the last value in `arr`, you need to add one to it to make a range that also includes that final index:

```
for k in range(p, r + 1):
#                 ^^^^^
```

Note that your code could be greatly reduced if you would use list slicing.

Comment: I'm still confused about why my bad version did still return the correct result with any number higher than 6.

Comment: Nevermind, I think it just snapped into place in my brain. Since the arr is modified as I'm sorting and merging any number higher than six is **already** in the last position (where it should be). So it is not meddled with.

Answer (score 1):

Brother you made a very small mistake in this line
`for k in range(p,r):`
Here you loop is running from p to r-1 and your last index i.e r, will not get iterated.
So you have to use
`for k in range(p,r+1):`

And in the second testcase `a=[2,4,5,7,1,2,3,8]`
You are getting the correct output even with your wrong code because you are overwriting the values in array `ar` and your current code was able to sort the array till index `r-1` and the number present at index r will be the same which was present before the execution of your merge function i.e 8

Try using this testcase: `[2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3, 7]`

And your output will be `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7]`

Hope this helped